# Selnium + Maven test run locally but fail in Azure Pipeline. Getting error "cannot access org.testng.Assert"

Tags: java, azure, maven, selenium-webdriver, azure-pipelines

When I run from TestNG or Maven test from locally all the test cases are working fine but in pipeline it gives me this "cannot access org.testng.Assert".
I am attaching the error screenshot of Azure Pipeline:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7EI5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhB5o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message:  class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0.

You should update Java version to at least Java 11.
Try adding  task  [Java Tool Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/java-tool-installer?view=azure-devops).

```
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '11'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'
```

Comment: Hi Minxin, Where should i update the java version? In Azure Pipeline or in my local machine?

Comment: If the pipeline runs in MS-host agent, you need to add  JavaToolInstaller task in pipeline. If run in local host agent, you  just need to ensure that the corresponding version of jdk version is installed in your machine.

Comment: Hi Minxin, after adding the Java Tool Installer task in azure pipeline, it worked. Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Comment: @Amir A Hi ,glad to know you've  resolved this issue!  If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing this issue because of JDK version on the Azure pipeline.
If you can check first if you have JDK and second what is the version.

```
java -version
```

Locally the tests work because the JDK version is the proper one.

Comment: Karamilov, In my machine I have JDK installed and its version is 11.

Comment: Can you check the jdk in azure pipeline